# Convert list of all folders and subfolders of unit c:\ to an XML file in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to make a small program in C # that allows to load a list with the path of all folders and subfolders of any unit, eg "C: \", to an XML or any other file type. The goal is that after this, the file will serve to another program that I have to do a search and open particular folder.

It is possible to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes.  But stackoverflow isn't a code writing service.  You have to try something yourself.  Come back and ask specific questions when you have them.

Comment: I don't want to ask the code!!!! Just need some lights!!!! for example who i transform the folders tree to a XML document....

Answer (score 0):

Some basic pointers (no, not those pointers!!)

For file enumeration, look at: Directory.EnumerateDirectories("C:/")

For Xml writing, look at XmlTextWriter.

Give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use recursion to travel through the folder structure. With it, you can pass XmlNode as a parameter in the recursion in order to add new child nodes (each sub folder is a child node, and so on in the recursive method)

Here is a sample of the recursion. Use it as a base

```
private static void FolderStructure(string path)
{
  Console.WriteLine(path);
  foreach (string item in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path))
  {
    FolderStructure(item);
  }
}

FolderStructure(@"X:\\My\\Path");
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do another program to test the creation of the XML file. Is working well, the file is created think correctly.
Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace generate_XML_open_folder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_generate_XML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string rootPath = combobox_rootpath.Text;
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath);

            var doc = new XDocument(GetDirectoryXml(dir));

            doc.Save("test.xml");
        }

        private void button_open_folder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textbox_folder_to_find_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void combobox_rootpath_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            combobox_rootpath.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string s in Directory.GetLogicalDrives())
            {

                combobox_rootpath.Items.Add(s);


            }
        }
        public static XElement GetDirectoryXml(DirectoryInfo dir)
        {
            var info = new XElement("dir",
                           new XAttribute("name", dir.Name));

            //foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
            // info.Add(new XElement("file",
            //  new XAttribute("name", file.Name)));

            foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
                info.Add(GetDirectoryXml(subDir));

            return info;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is an example of the content of the XML file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dir name="h:\">
  <dir name="System Volume Information" />
  <dir name="xp1000" />
  <dir name="Procura_Desenhos">
    <dir name="Procura_Desenhos">
      <dir name="Resources" />
      <dir name="Properties" />
      <dir name="obj">
        <dir name="Release" />
        <dir name="Debug">
          <dir name="TempPE" />
          <dir name="Refactor" />
        </dir>
      </dir>
      <dir name="bin">
        <dir name="Release" />
        <dir name="Debug" />
      </dir>
    </dir>
  </dir>
  <dir name="Procura_Desenhos1.1">
    <dir name="Procura_Desenhos1.1">
      <dir name="bin">
        <dir name="Debug" />
        <dir name="Release" />
      </dir>
      <dir name="obj">
        <dir name="Debug">
          <dir name="TempPE" />
        </dir>
      </dir>
      <dir name="Properties" />
      <dir name="Resources" />
    </dir>
  </dir>
  <dir name="Backup">
    <dir name="Visual 2008">
      <dir name="Projects">
        <dir name="Procura_Desenhos">
          <dir name="Procura_Desenhos">
            <dir name="Resources" />
            <dir name="Properties" />
            <dir name="obj">
              <dir name="Release" />
              <dir name="Debug">
                <dir name="TempPE" />
                <dir name="Refactor" />
              </dir>
            </dir>
            <dir name="bin">
              <dir name="Release" />
              <dir name="Debug" />
            </dir>
          </dir>
        </dir>
      </dir>
    </dir>
    <dir name="Visual 2005">
      <dir name="Projects">
        <dir name="WindowsApplication1">
          <dir name="WindowsApplication1">
            <dir name="obj">
              <dir name="Release" />
              <dir name="Debug">
                <dir name="TempPE" />
              </dir>
            </dir>
            <dir name="My Project" />
            <dir name="bin">
              <dir name="Release" />
              <dir name="Debug" />
            </dir>
          </dir>
        </dir>
        <dir name="Procura">
          <dir name="Procura">
            <dir name="Resources" />
            <dir name="obj">
              <dir name="Release" />
              <dir name="Debug">
                <dir name="TempPE" />
              </dir>
            </dir>
            <dir name="My Project" />
            <dir name="bin">
              <dir name="Release" />
              <dir name="Debug" />
            </dir>
          </dir>
        </dir>
        <dir name="find_v1.1">
          <dir name="_UpgradeReport_Files" />
          <dir name="find_v1.1">
            <dir name="Properties" />
            <dir name="obj">
              <dir name="Release" />
              <dir name="Debug">
                <dir name="TempPE" />
              </dir>
            </dir>
            <dir name="bin">
              <dir name="Release" />
              <dir name="Debug" />
            </dir>
          </dir>
          <dir name="Backup">
            <dir name="find_v1.1">
              <dir name="Properties" />
            </dir>
          </dir>
        </dir>
        <dir name="find_v1.0">
          <dir name="find_v1.0">
            <dir name="Properties" />
            <dir name="obj">
              <dir name="Release" />
              <dir name="Debug">
                <dir name="TempPE" />
              </dir>
            </dir>
            <dir name="bin">
              <dir name="Release" />
              <dir name="Debug" />
            </dir>
          </dir>
        </dir>
      </dir>
    </dir>
  </dir>
</dir>
```

Now what I want is to enter in textbox_folder_to_find the name of the folder to look in , the program searchs in the XML file for the path of that folder  and after having the path is opened with shellExecute or explorer.
Does anyone know how I can do this?